# msbuild DevTools.Target /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Win32"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Running command
**msbuild DevTools.Target /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Win32"**
fails with error

```
 Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.225]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.
Build started 1/7/2014 2:24:12 PM.
Project "t:\DevTools.Target" on node 1 (default targets).
LoadInfo:
  Built PROJECT as C:\XXX
  Gathering Version information
  IS BUILD MACHINE: false
  Next Build #  : 
  Will this run increment the build  : yes
Project "t:\PROJECT\DevTools.Target" (1) is building "T:\solution.sln" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
T:\solution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "|Debug|Win32" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. 
Build FAILED.
```

Win32 platform DOES exist in solution and I able to build Solution successfully from IDE

Thing is that this is no ordinary SLN file passed to msbuild but instead its TARGET (XML) file.
**How can I force msbuild to use "Win32" platform during build ?**

Answer (score 1):

see the error, you've got something wrong in your devtools.target: it tries to build `"|Debug|Win32"` but that should be `"Debug|Win32"`